# How to make background and border entire viewport but keep content inside container

Tags: html, css

How would I make the background colour and border stretch the entire viewport width but keep the content inside the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7808/

So basically I need the background and border to stretch the entire viewport width but keep the content inside the different colours

HTML:

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">

            <div class="blue">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    something will go in here
                </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                    something will go in here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="green">
                something will go in here
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

header .col-sm-8, header .col-sm-4, header .col-sm-6 {
    padding: 0;
}

.green {
    background: #f4f9f5;
    border-top: 7px solid #a9cab3;
    border-left: 7px solid #a9cab3;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.blue {
    background: #c9dee3;
    border-top: 7px solid #70c9d9;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
}

.blue .col-sm-6 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you were looking for!

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="blue">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        column 1.1
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        column 1.2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="green">
                    column 2.1
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

header {
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.green {
    background: #f4f9f5;
    border: 7px solid #a9cab3;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.blue {
    background: #c9dee3;
    border: 7px solid #70c9d9;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
```